# zmq_ctx_destroy freezes - how to solve?

Tags: zeromq

New zeromq user here. I have a PUB-SUB system, and this used to work fine before. I refactored the code a bit, and the application freezes in the context destruction:

```
zmq_close(subscriberSocket);
zmq_ctx_destroy(context); // freezes here
```

I have closed `subscriberSocket`, so is it possible that either it is still not closed, or if there is another open socket?

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/2330), and it suggests setting `ZMQ_LINGER`. So, I added this line before the socket creation:

```
int size = 0;
zmq_setsockopt(subscriberSocket, ZMQ_LINGER, &size, sizeof(int));
```

However, this still does not work.

How should I check what's going on, e.g. check blocking sockets, and force them to close?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Most likely another socket, are you running with multiple threads? The first thing I do in these situations is run in `gdb` , break in and check the stack of each thread usually finding the offending blocking socket.

Comment: Sorry I just returned to this issue. Yeah it is quite probably a combination of the parent application (I was writing the above code in a plugin) and my implementation as a singleton. Implemented the same thing in an independent application and it was fine. Not very sure how to solve it, so my workaround was simply to not implement it as a singleton.

Comment: In an application I wrote a while back, the way I solved this was to first shutdown the context, and then close the sockets. The application which was written in Java and the sockets were created and used in a thread pool, but the context was created in the main thread. At the end of the application, I first shutdown the context which will cause all sockets to return from any blocking operations, then I shutdown the threadpool which will now interrupt the socket threads, then I wait for the threadpool to finish. This process always gives me a clean exit.